# What is the connection of these definitions of a Permutation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

sorry if the title is confusing, I didn't know how else to phrase this question.

I know that a permutation is "the number of ways something can be uniquely ordered." The classic example is you have a standard deck of cards, and so there are 52! unique ways to arrange said deck of cards.

But, I have learned that a permutation on a set A is just a bijection of the set A that maps to itself. So, assuming f is bijective,

f: A -> A

I am just confused trying to relate these two concepts and seeking some insight to help me understand this. Thank you!

Comment: When the set is $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ then interpreting the "arrangement" of the numbers as a function which maps the *location* to the *number*, then both definitions match.  E.g. for $\{1,2,3,4\}$ the arrangement $3124$ corresponds to the first digit being $3$, the second digit being $1$, etc... i.e. the function (*which is a bijection here*) $f:\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ where $\begin{cases} f(1)=3\\f(2)=1\\f(3)=2\\f(4)=4\end{cases}$.  For sets other than $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, if you prefer, think of an additional bijection *to* $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ first and then continue.

Comment: You write that `I know a permutation is "the number of ways something can be uniquely ordered.` That is not correct. **A** permutation could be though as **an** ordering, but not a permutation as the number of orderings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have a deck of 3 cards only; say the ace, two and three of diamonds.

There are also three places in the deck a card may occur: first, second and third.

So, an "arrangement" of the deck corresponds to a mapping from the set of cards, to the set of places the card may occur in. Because these both have the same cardinality (see what I did there?), it's convenient to use the same set, namely: $S = \{1,2,3\}$ to index *both* sets.

This gives a bijection between two sets of bijections:

Set $1$: $\{\text{set of cards}\} \to \{\text{set of positions}\}$

Set $2: S \to S$.

For example, the arrangment: "ace of diamonds, three of diamonds, two of diamonds" can be thought of as the mapping:

$\text{ace}\mapsto \text{first}\\
\text{two} \mapsto \text{third}\\
\text{three} \mapsto \text{second}$

which then corresponds to the mapping:

$1 \mapsto 1\\
2\mapsto 3\\
3 \mapsto 2$

which is often thought of as a transposition, or "swap" of the last two cards. Other possible arrangements are mapped into bijections $S \to S$ in a similar fashion.

The idea is pretty much the same for sets of larger cardinalities (but a bit more tedious to work out).

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Think of the “slots” into which elements of $A$ can be placed as being labeled by elements of $A$. For any $a\in A$, then, the function $f$ tells you what’s in the slot labeled “$a$.”